# My webview is blank

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have two ImageButton with two different url. When I click the image, it returns an white screen.I don't know what is the problem. Any edit or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

**main activity**

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        ImageButton amazon = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
        ImageButton flipkart = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton2);

        amazon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Amazon",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// display the toast on home button click
                Intent intent  = new Intent(main.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.com"));
                WebView webview = new WebView(main.this);
                setContentView(webview);

                startActivity(intent);



            }
        });
        flipkart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Flipkart",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// display the toast on you tube button click
                Intent intent  = new Intent(main.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.flipkart.in"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

**my webview activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView htmlWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    htmlWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSetting = htmlWebView.getSettings();
    webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    htmlWebView.loadUrl("");
}



 class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're never setting the url. You need to use getIntent() inside of MainActivity to get the value of the data you are passing the class.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to load Url in your app or want to open via External Browser. anaway I'm given the snipped code for the open the url in webview as given below in your application as:

```
   WebView mynews;
        ProgressBar pb;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.newsreadscreen);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        pb= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            mynews= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mynews);
            mynews.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mynews.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(17);
            mynews.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
            mynews.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            mynews.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);



            mynews.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                 pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                  pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                }
            });

   mynews.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in");
```

this is the code I have Edited

```
 amazon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Amazon",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// display the toast on home button click
                Intent intent  = new Intent(main.this, MainActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("url","http://www.amazon.com");
                startActivity(intent);



            }
        });
```

get the value on the MainActivity.Class onCreateMethod like below

```
String url=getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
mynews.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: i want the url to be open inside app.

Comment: i will try asap and get back to the comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot in advance mate !

Comment: Okay bro i have edited post because you to pass your url to load i have directly passed google link if you found this helpful please upvote it. Thank You Happy Coding...

Comment: yes it works, but i have to image button, so i want  to add two different url? any suggestions?

Comment: you can change the url on Image Button click

Comment: i have passed the direct link bro you can change it as your need.

Comment: I have gave the sample code to send the url from one activity to another as above edited may this helpful for you

Comment: if you problem solved accept the answer and upvote it. Thank You